# Getting ModuleNotFound errors in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forwardSpam.py", line 5, in <module>
    from email.Header import Header
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.Header'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forwardSpam.py", line 6, in <module>
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.mime.text'
```

These are the errors that I get when trying to use this script off github

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't dowloaded the module. If you're using pycharm *Preferences > Projects > Python Interpreter* > Find the email module and add that.

Or you can just pip install the module from your terminal which is

```
   pip install email
```

(but if you're using different ide you need to look where you can add modules) that way you downloaded the module for calling in the script that you wrote.

I think that should do the work.

And also
`from email.Header import Header`  You can just say

```
 from email import Header
```

or any other callable specific function after installing the module.

Comment: Didn't work, see here:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXX.py", line 5, in <module>
    from email import Header
ImportError: cannot import name 'Header' from 'email' (C:\Users\Devan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\__init__.py)

C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\Coding crap\spambot\Email\emailSpam>py forwardSpam.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forwardSpam.py", line 5, in <module>
    from email import Header
ImportError: cannot import name 'Header' from 'email' (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\email\__init__.py)

Comment: There should be package error or pip version error, I tried pip install and it gave me error for installing email module .You can check your pip version and compatiable module version for installing.

Comment: `python -m pip install --user email` that should work